# Overlay of multiple image sources with layer stack-order, with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

*Note: I've already read a few questions/answers about `[ffmpeg]` `overlay`, but it did not fully answer this.*

Let's say we have five inputs `[0]` ... `[4]` that can be images, videos, etc.

I'd like to overlay them in a precise order, a bit like "Photoshop layers" or CSS [`z-index`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp).

Currently I use `ffmpeg` with a "recursive" use of `overlay` like this:

```
   -filter_complex "
        [0]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[s0];
        [1]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS+3/TB[s1];
        [2]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS+7/TB[s2];
        [3]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS+8/TB[s3];
        [4]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS+9/TB[s4];
        [s0][s1]overlay=enable='between(t,3,13)'[o1];
        [o1][s2]overlay=enable='between(t,7,12)'[o2];
        [o2][s3]overlay=enable='between(t,8,15)'[o3];
        [o3][s4]overlay=enable='between(t,9,12)'[o4];
   "
```

**Question**: with `ffmpeg`, is there a way to do a mixing of different input image "layers":

- in a shorter way that this recursive use of `overlay`
- and such that we can specify the "stack order" of each layer, like with CSS `z-index`

?

To give a concrete example, how would you modify the previous command such that:

- from 0'00" to 0'10", the layer order (from background to foreground) is 0, 1, 2, 3, 4
- from 0'10" to 0'15", the layer order (from background to foreground) is 2, 3, 1, 4, 0 (i.e. `[0]` goes to foreground)

?